# Iterate on items in Array with Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am looking to iterate on items within an array using python and create folders for items.

The following is my format:

```
'0001': ['123101203', '1221231102136'], 
'0002': ['1681235932', '22612312303', '213412312341', '123123610116'], 
'0003': ['123408503']
```

What I am looking to do is to look through the Array and create Folders for each item and subfolders for each sub-item.

i.e. there is a 0001 folder, and within it there is a 1230101203 folder and a 1222.. folder , etc.

I was approaching it like the following:

```
sample = [Array]
for s in sample:       
   os.mkdir(n)
   os.chdir(n + '/')
        Create subfolders for each array item
   # os.chdir('../')
```

Comment: ... What's the question here?

Comment: will you go on this nested structure or it stops in 2d?

Comment: I am wondering how to loop through the array and through each of its items. I was thinking a nested structure makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add error handling for existing directories, but you can do the following in order to not have to worry about nested loops or building up the path:

```
from os import makedirs, path
from itertools import product, chain

data = {
    '0001': ['123101203', '1221231102136'],
    '0002': ['1681235932', '22612312303', '213412312341', '123123610116'],
    '0003': ['123408503']
}

dirs = chain(*list(product((k,), v) for k, v in data.items()))
for parent, sub in dirs:
    makedirs(path.join(parent, sub))
```

Comment: This is great! If there are existing directories is there an easy way to overwrite it?

Comment: @user1982011: You can check for its existence beforehand (`os.path.exists` and `os.path.isdir`) and delete it using `shutil.rmtree`.

Answer (score 1):

So pretty much what you want to do is a nested loop. 
As sample looks a bit like a dict, you have first to get the keys of the dict to access the lines of your "array".

```
for s in sample.keys(): 
   # mkfolder for 1st level; s is storing the key name
   for i in sample[s]:
       # do the rest of the folders
```

Of course you might need to build up the path, but this should be not a big issue as you have s and different i.